# Is the work for this power series problem correct?

Tags: calculus, power-series

Here are the problems:

[image]

For my work:

I understand $$f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^na^nf(x)$$
So, the Taylor series is:
$$1-ax+\frac{a^2}{2!}x^2-\frac{a^3}{3!}x^3...$$
The general term would be:
$$e^{-ax}$$

As for the familiar function, I believe it is:
$$e^{-ax}$$ or $$e^{ax}$$
(I'm not entirely sure).

However, for the last problem, I've gone up to n = 7 and I still haven't gone below 0.001. Here is what I've done so far:
$$1-2(0.2)+\frac{2^2}{2!}(0.2)^2-\frac{2^3}{3!}(0.2)^3...-\frac{2^7}{7!}(0.2)^7=0.65973$$
Is there a way to shorten the process?

Comment: @sku Why should the OP do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $f(x)=e^{-ax}$, since$$f(x)=1-ax+\frac{a^2}{2!}x^2-\frac{a^3}{3!}x^3+\cdots=e^{-ax}.$$If $a=2$, then $f(x)=e^{-2x}$. If$$f_n(x)=1-2x+\frac{2^2}{2!}x^2-\frac{2^3}{3!}x^3+\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{2^n}{n!}x^n,$$then$$f(x)-f_n(x)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^{n+1}e^{-2t}}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1},$$for some $t$ between $0$ and $x$. So, when $x=0.2$,$$\bigl|f(x)-f_n(x)\bigr|\leqslant\frac{0.2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$and therefore it is enough to have$$\frac{2^{n+1}\times0.2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}<0.001.$$You can take $n=4$, since$$\frac{2^5\times0.2^5}{5!}=\frac{2^{10}\times0.1^5}{120}=\frac{1\,024}{120}10^{-4}<10^{-3}.$$And $f_4(0.2)=0.6704$, whereas $f(0.2)\approx0.670\,32$.

Comment: Ok, thank you! So the general term that I have is the same as the familiar function?

Comment: I don't understand why is it that you call it “general term”, but, yes, the familiar function is $e^{-ax}$.

Comment: @amateurmath Your understanding of what the general term is, it is incorrect. The general term refers to the formula for each of the individual terms being summed in the series, not the thing the series sums to. In this case, the general term is $$\frac{(-1)^na^nx^n}{n!}=\frac{(-ax)^n}{n!},$$ which, when summed, results in $$e^{-ax}.$$